# Bootstrap Navbar will not collapse on smart phone

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

It appears I have everything in the right place.

**In the head. No viewport meta tag(I tried but no luck)**

```
<title>My Title for Webpage</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Right above the  closing tag**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Here is the the navbar html**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 30px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="title">Portland Dancing</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="max-height: 100%;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                    EnableViewState="false" DataTextField="DanceStyle" DataValueField="DanceStyle">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChooseDateRanges" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DateRangePullDownHandler" EnableViewState="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All Days">All Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Christmas">Christmas</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="New Years Eve">New Year's Eve</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Today">Today</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Today Tomorrow">Today Tomorrow</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="This Weekend">This Weekend</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Next Weekend">Next Weekend</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="This Week">This Week</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Fridays">Fridays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Saturdays">Saturdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sundays">Sundays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mondays">Mondays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tuesdays">Tuesdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Wednesdays">Wednesdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Thursdays">Thursdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 1pm">Before 1pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 3pm">Before 3pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 6pm">Before 6pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 9pm">Before 9pm</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrint" Style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 6px 0px;" CssClass="form-control"
                    CausesValidation="False" BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"
                    EnableViewState="false" title="Make your choices with the checkboxes and then Print them">Print</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmail" Style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 6px 0px;" CssClass="form-control"
                    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black"
                    EnableViewState="false" title="Make your choices with the checkboxes and then Email them">
            Email
                </asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgesPrice" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AgesPricePulldownHandler"
                    CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="false" Style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ages, Price" Enabled="false">(Ages, Price)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All, All">All, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All, Free">All, Free</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Under 21, All">Under 21, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Under 21, Free">Under 21, Free</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Over 50, All">Over 50, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Over 50, Free">Over 50, Free</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInflate" CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="True"
                    BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black" Style="margin-bottom: 5px;" runat="Server"
                    ToolTip="Check/Uncheck the box to have all the names expand with more info on this web page. Or go over and click on an event name to pop up a whole bunch of information.">
                </asp:CheckBox></li>
            <li>
            <a href="emailus.aspx" class="form-control" style="color: black; background-color: #f6f2dc; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 14px; padding: 6px 0px;" target="_blank" title="Do you have a dance to list? Problem with a listing? Advice for us? Click here to email us. Classes and workshops are in a different area: Learn Stuff">
                Contact</a>
             </li>
            <li>
            <a href="learn.aspx" target="_blank" class="form-control" style="font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: 7px; color: Red; background-color: #f6f2dc; font-size: 14px; padding: 6px 0px;"
                title="You must click here to see the Lessons, Worksops, and Gatherings, Private Lessons.">
                Lessons</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is what it looks like on an iphone 5 using the Chrome Developer tools. This is same on my iphone6plus. It should be collapsed and showing toggle button in the right:**

[image: Navbar collapsed to iphone5 size]

**Here is in regular browser size (laptop) using the Chrome Developer tools. As designed:**

[image: Regular/Laptop browser size]

**What is funny and has me confused is that I can shrink my Chrome browser window by dragging in the right side of the window and the Toggle Button shows up and works. It kinda shows that I am doing pretty much the right thing. . . until I try on my iPhone6plus**

[image: Window shrink navbar]

**And I also collapsed my li tags and took a screen print in an effort to see things better:**

[image]

Comment: Try setting the viewport: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`.

Comment: Please post the full source code, with the snippets you've provided, its going to be fairly difficult to locate the issue.

Comment: @Karin you are right! Hey, I had problems before with the viewoport. While I was editing this question you answered it. Man that was fast. If it was a snake it would have bit me. However. . . .I need to upload it and open it on my smartass phone. Please make this an answer so I can accept it if it works on my phone. thank you

Comment: Well, it works on my iphone6plus after putting the "meta viewport" tag back in. I did post the full source code. And also a screen print of it shrunk. So, I'm off to the next brain twister.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment, adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the `head` section should fix your issue. You can read more about viewports [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), but the takeaway is:

> The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the
>   screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page
>   is first loaded by the browser.

So, this lets the mobile phone know to not squish your webpage and that it's designed with mobile scaling in mind :)

Comment: I ran into all those explanations during this long 2 days of trying to get things to work. Thank you google and Stack Overflow. I think it was messing up the body part of my shrunken screen and that is another story for another bed time. One tiny step at a time. thank you @Karin . . .. Man, it's tough trying to make an old asp.net webforms website responsive. The devil is in the details.  I suppose I could go the "skinny underfed" look of a boilerplate bootstrap template. Abbreviation for Boot Strap is. . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

```html
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 30px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="title">Portland Dancing</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="max-height: 100%;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                    EnableViewState="false" DataTextField="DanceStyle" DataValueField="DanceStyle">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChooseDateRanges" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DateRangePullDownHandler" EnableViewState="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All Days">All Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Christmas">Christmas</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="New Years Eve">New Year's Eve</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Today">Today</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Today Tomorrow">Today Tomorrow</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="This Weekend">This Weekend</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Next Weekend">Next Weekend</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="This Week">This Week</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Fridays">Fridays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Saturdays">Saturdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sundays">Sundays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mondays">Mondays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tuesdays">Tuesdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Wednesdays">Wednesdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Thursdays">Thursdays</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 1pm">Before 1pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 3pm">Before 3pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 6pm">Before 6pm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Before 9pm">Before 9pm</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrint" Style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 6px 0px;" CssClass="form-control"
                    CausesValidation="False" BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"
                    EnableViewState="false" title="Make your choices with the checkboxes and then Print them">Print</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmail" Style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 6px 0px;" CssClass="form-control"
                    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black"
                    EnableViewState="false" title="Make your choices with the checkboxes and then Email them">
            Email
                </asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgesPrice" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AgesPricePulldownHandler"
                    CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="false" Style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ages, Price" Enabled="false">(Ages, Price)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All, All">All, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="All, Free">All, Free</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Under 21, All">Under 21, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Under 21, Free">Under 21, Free</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Over 50, All">Over 50, All</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Over 50, Free">Over 50, Free</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInflate" CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="True"
                    BackColor="#f6f2dc" ForeColor="Black" Style="margin-bottom: 5px;" runat="Server"
                    ToolTip="Check/Uncheck the box to have all the names expand with more info on this web page. Or go over and click on an event name to pop up a whole bunch of information.">
                </asp:CheckBox></li>
            <li>
            <a href="emailus.aspx" class="form-control" style="color: black; background-color: #f6f2dc; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 14px; padding: 6px 0px;" target="_blank" title="Do you have a dance to list? Problem with a listing? Advice for us? Click here to email us. Classes and workshops are in a different area: Learn Stuff">
                Contact</a>
             </li>
            <li>
            <a href="learn.aspx" target="_blank" class="form-control" style="font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: 7px; color: Red; background-color: #f6f2dc; font-size: 14px; padding: 6px 0px;"
                title="You must click here to see the Lessons, Worksops, and Gatherings, Private Lessons.">
                Lessons</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the original post *"In the head. No viewport meta tag(I tried but no luck)"*

Comment: @Head In Cloud, I upvoted you because while I was editing the question to add the comment about viewport you answer this for me. Thank you for such a quick response and don't give up on me.